# no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:47 in Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have been using their algorithm for days and I tried several, but none of them gave me this error until now.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-dbd18151b569> in <module>()
      1 from demo import load_checkpoints
      2 generator, kp_detector = load_checkpoints(config_path='config/vox-256.yaml', 
----> 3                             checkpoint_path='/content/gdrive/My Drive/first-order-motion-model/vox-cpk.pth.tar')

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in _lazy_init()
    188             raise AssertionError(
    189                 "libcudart functions unavailable. It looks like you have a broken build?")
--> 190         torch._C._cuda_init()
    191         # Some of the queued calls may reentrantly call _lazy_init();
    192         # we need to just return without initializing in that case.

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (100) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:47
```

Answer (score 4):

You have not enabled GPU on your notebook, enable it in `Runtime > Change runtime.`